# Maximizing the ratio of largest eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, stability

Let $K$ be a real stable matrix; more specifically,
$$
K=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0&1&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&1&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\ldots&1\\
-k_0&-k_1&-k_2&\ldots&-k_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $k_0,\ldots,k_{n-1}>0$. Is there a (non-numerical) algorithm for obtaining the real symmetric positive definite $P$ that maximizes the value

$$
\sigma=\frac{-\lambda_{\max}\left( K^T P+ PK \right)}{\lambda_{\max}(P)}?
$$

Or, at least, is it possible to estimate $\sigma$ for a given $K$? 
I understand that I can solve the Lyapunov equation $K^T P+ PK=Q$ for some $Q<0$ and use the obtained $P$ to calculate the estimation. But, maybe, there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-numerical algorithm"? You want an explicit formula for $\sigma$?

Comment: @Federico Poloni I am looking for something more appropriate than just a generic constrained optimization. LMI problem formulation, for example. But if such an explicit formula exists, it will be just fine