# Maximizing a certain eigenvalue ratio

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an Hurwitz stable matrix (i.e., the spectrum of $A$ lies on the left-half complex plane) and let $P$ be the unique positive definite solution of the following Lyapunov equation
$$
AP+PA^\top = -Q,
$$
where $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite matrix. Moreover, let $\lambda_{\min}(X)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(X)$ denote the smallest and largest (resp.) eigenvalue of the positive definite matrix $X$.

> **My question.** For which positive definite $Q$ the following ratio 
>   $$
> r(Q) = \frac{\lambda_\min(Q)}{\lambda_\max(P)}
> $$
>   is maximized and what is the value of the maximum?

Comment: Related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249052/91764).